# How can I split certain phrase a String?

Tags: regex, string, split, match

I have String with some search items and I want to split them in an array of String.

Example:

```
String text = "java example \"this is a test\" hello world";
```

I want to get the following results

```
result[0] = "java";
result[1] = "example";
result[2] = "\"this is a test\"";
result[3] = "hello";
result[4] = "world";
```

In short, I want to combine text.split(" ") and text.split("\"");
Is there an easy way to code it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `String#split` method:

```
(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\s+
```

**Code:**

```
String text = "java example \"this is a test\" hello world";
String[] tok = text.split("(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\s+");
// print the array
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arr ) );
```

**Output:**

```
[java, example, "this is a test", hello, world]
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should match `(\\".+?\\")|([^\s]+)`

It matches anything within `\"` including the `\"` OR single words.

Check here for results: http://www.regexr.com/399a4

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused and there are errors in your code!
Composing your string should be:

```
String text = "java example \"this is a test\" hello world";
```

The value of the variable `text` would then be:

```
java example "this is a test" hello world
```

I am rather assuming that you want to extract this into the following array:

```
result[0] = "java";
result[1] = "example";
result[2] = "\"this is a test\"";
result[3] = "hello";
result[4] = "world";
```

You can do this by using a regular expression, for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = "java example \"this is a test\" hello world";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:\"[a-z\\s]+\")|[a-z]+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(m.find()) {
            lst.add(m.group(1));
        }

        String[] result= new String[lst.size()];
        result = lst.toArray(results);

        for(String s: result) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The regular expression `((?:\"[a-z\\s]+\")|[a-z]+)` will match on either:
1) sequences of characters `a` to `z` or whitespace between double quotes
2) sequence of characters `a` to `z`.

We then extract these matches using `m.find`

Comment: thank you. your are right. I just wrote my code without testing it  on my compiler.